# Infinite Scrolling - Get the Div ID of Dynamically Updated Content

Tags: php, jquery, html

So I'm creating infinite scrolling for my blog. It should essentially pull out ONE post after the scroll. 
I'm pulling it through Ajax. The problem is, Ajax is posting the same post_id which I got after one scroll. I debugged it with firebug.
For example: There is already a post with the post-id = 10. After I scroll, it appends the next post with the post-id = 11. But scrolls after that, it only appends the post with the post-id = 11, it does not append the post with the post-id = 12 and so on. What is the problem? Is there a problem with this (Posted:last) selector? How do I get the id of the last dynamically updated content?

Here is my Index.php:

```
<?php
include 'resources/init.php';

function get_posts($post_id = null, $tag_id = null){
    $posts = array();
    $query = "SELECT `posts`.`post_id` AS `posts_id`, `tags`.`tag_id` AS `tags_id`,
                        `title`, `txt_content`, `img_content`, `date_posted`,`tag_name`
                        FROM `posts`
                        INNER JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`tag_id` = `posts`.`tag_id`";

    if(isset($post_id)){
        $post_id = (int)$post_id;
        $query .= " WHERE `posts`.`post_id` = $post_id";

    }
    if(isset($tag_id)){
        $tag_id = (int)$tag_id;
        $query .= " WHERE `tags`.`tag_id` = $tag_id";

    }

    $query .= " ORDER BY `posts`.`post_id` DESC LIMIT 0,1";

    $query = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $posts[] = $row;
    }
    return $posts;
}

$posts = (isset($_GET['post_id'])) ? get_posts($_GET['post_id']) : get_posts();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href = "http://localhost/simpleblog/add_post.php">Add a Post</a> | <a href = "http://localhost/simpleblog/add_tag.php">Add a Tag</a> | <a href = "http://localhost/simpleblog/tag_list.php">Show Existing Tags</a> | <a href = ""></a>
<p>
<div id = "AddPosts">
<?php
foreach($posts as $post){
?>
    <div class = "Posted" id = "<?php echo $post['posts_id']; ?>">
    <h2><a href = "http://localhost/simpleblog/looks/<?php echo $post['posts_id']; ?>-<?php $strings = array(" "); echo str_replace($strings, '-', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 s]/', '', $post['title'])); ?>"><?php echo $post['title'];?></a></h2>
    <div><?php echo nl2br($post['txt_content']);?></div>
    <div><img src = "http://localhost/simpleblog/<?php echo $post['img_content'];?>"></div>
        <p>Posted on <i><?php echo date("F dS\,\ Y", strtotime($post['date_posted'])); ?></i>
         in <a href = "http://localhost/simpleblog/tags/<?php echo $post['tags_id'];?>"><?php echo $post['tag_name']; ?></a></p>
         <div><a href = "http://localhost/simpleblog/edit_my_looks/<?php echo $post['posts_id'];?>">Edit This Post</a> |
        <a href = "http://localhost/simpleblog/delte_my_post/<?php echo $post['posts_id'];?>"> Delete This Post</a></div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
<center><img src = "loader.gif" id = "loading-img" width = "200" height = "200" style = "display:none" /></center>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        $('#loading-img').show();

        var post_id = $('.Posted:last').attr('id');
        $.post("add_more_posts.php", {post_id: post_id} , function(data){
            if(data){
                $('#loading-img').fadeOut();
                $('#AddPosts').append(data);
            }else{
                $('#AddPosts').append('Finished Loading!');
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Add_more_posts.php

```
<?php
include 'resources/init.php';

function load_more_posts($post_id = null, $tag_id = null){
    $posts = array();
    $query = "SELECT `posts`.`post_id` AS `posts_id`, `tags`.`tag_id` AS `tags_id`,
                        `title`, `txt_content`, `img_content`, `date_posted`,`tag_name`
                        FROM `posts`
                        INNER JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`tag_id` = `posts`.`tag_id`";

    if(isset($post_id)){
        $post_id = (int)$_POST['post_id'];
        $query .= " WHERE `posts`.`post_id` < $post_id";

    }
    if(isset($tag_id)){
        $tag_id = (int)$tag_id;
        $query .= " WHERE `tags`.`tag_id` = $tag_id";

    }

    $query .= " ORDER BY `posts`.`post_id` DESC LIMIT 0,1";

    $query = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $posts[] = $row;
    }
    return $posts;
}

$posts = (isset($_POST['post_id'])) ? load_more_posts($_POST['post_id']) : load_more_posts();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
foreach($posts as $post){
?>
    <h2><a href = "http://localhost/simpleblog/looks/<?php echo $post['posts_id']; ?>-<?php $strings = array(" "); echo str_replace($strings, '-', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 s]/', '', $post['title'])); ?>"><?php echo $post['title'];?></a></h2>
    <div><?php echo nl2br($post['txt_content']);?></div>
    <div><img src = "http://localhost/simpleblog/<?php echo $post['img_content'];?>"></div>
        <p>Posted on <i><?php echo date("F dS\,\ Y", strtotime($post['date_posted'])); ?></i>
         in <a href = "http://localhost/simpleblog/tags/<?php echo $post['tags_id'];?>"><?php echo $post['tag_name']; ?></a></p>
         <div><a href = "http://localhost/simpleblog/edit_my_looks/<?php echo $post['posts_id'];?>">Edit This Post</a> |
        <a href = "http://localhost/simpleblog/delte_my_post/<?php echo $post['posts_id'];?>"> Delete This Post</a></div>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is an idea why it might not be working.

On the ajax site there might be problem keeping track of the fetched id. If you are fetching a record with id=12. How are you keeping track of this record? So your problem might be that ajax is sending the same id over and over again to the server, thats why its not fetching the next record.

you can create static variables in javascript by

```
function static_vars(){
    this.id=0;
}
```

and later you can call it from any function

```
static_vars.id
```

So once you fetch record 12 update static_vars.id to 13 and send the id to server for fetching the reocrd 13.

Increment static_vars.id only if you get a successfull response from server.

Comment: Yes, Ajax IS sending the same ID over and over again! But wait, I don't get how I would implement into this code? Please help, thanks!

Comment: Ok for me to help you, You have to tell me your approach on client side(jquery/javascript)? how are you keeping track of record id's or page index on client side?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, I thought this would work. I learned this pagination technique from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNWWKfBtysk

Comment: It works in his video, its just not working in mine. And I don't think he keeps track of the post_ids.

Comment: If you are fetching a single record then you don't need to learn pagination. On client side just send the id of the record you want to fetch from server eg. you want to fetch record 6 from server through ajax. once you receive the response update this id to 7 on client side and so on. But if you dont know how to do these things then i suggest you build up your skills. You need to develop a proper algorithm for you problem.

Comment: Alrite, I see what you mean. Thanks! But the question is, how come its working in that video and not in mine?

Comment: or you can use json response from server to send content as well as next record id to client and then you can use this id to fetch the next record.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26317/discussion-between-cole-and-muhammad-nasir)